# Running openmdao 1.7.0 GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, openmdao

Is openmdao GUI available on 1.7.0 version? And if yes, how to run it? I have found, how to run the GUI on the 0.10.7 version, but it doesn't work on the 1.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We no longer have a GUI, and certain changes that we made to improve performance and maintainability have made it unlikely that OpenMDAO is capable of being run interactively like it was before.

However, we have been working on some visualization tools. You should definitely check out the N2 viewer:

```
from openmdao.api import view_tree
view_tree(my_problem)
```

It is useful for picturing the data-flow structure of your model. We are working on a tutorial/example for it that will added to the docs pretty soon.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the paraboloid example and got this error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Applications\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\openmdao\\devtools\\partition_tree_n2.‌​template' . When I checked on the devtools package, I have the partition_tree_n2.py file.

Comment: It works fine, my problem was that I install openMDAO with the pip install openmdao and not with the github repository. Unfortunetely, when you install openmdao without the github repo, it doesn't contain the partition.tree_n2.template file. Thanks

Comment: I think we may have just fixed this on our latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after updating to 1.7.1 via pip on Fedora v20. The command with conventional naming is:

> > view_tree(top)